# Cinema 4d How to move an Axis Point when something is already keyframed

Tags: animation, 3d, point, cinema-4d

I created an animation in cinema 4d, now I want to go back and change the axis point of one of my objects. If I move it, and hit return the object moves to a new position (this partially makes sense because the position is relative. I'm wondering id the is some way to move the axis point, without effecting the position of the polygon that I already animated.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming related question? If it is, you might want to clarify. Otherwise it's off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you animate the position of an object you actually animate the position of its axis point and if you move the axis point, it goes back to the position it should have according to your animation and as a result, moving your object...as you already noticed.

You could create a null object and copy&paste the keyframes of your object to it, then set your object as a child of the null and delete the keyframes from your object. That way you get the animation from the null and you can safely change the axis point of your object.